# Update custom data for customer

Tags: attributes, customer, event-observer, magento2.3

I'm trying to Create new customer attribute **"last_login_at"** to store customer last login date time. My requirement is to update **"last_login_at"** data for the customer after the **customer logged in**. I really don't know how to update it with an **observer**. Can anybody help me?
Many thanks,

Here is my code for creating the `attribute`:

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(),'2.2.17','<')){
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
      $attributeCode = 'last_login_at';


        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, // customer entity code
            'last_login_at',
            [

                'label' =>"Last Login",
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'input' => 'date',
                'frontend' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\Datetime::class,
                'backend' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime::class,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'input_filter' => 'date',
                'validate_rules' => '{"input_validation":"date"}',
                'position'     => 999,


            ]
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            null,
            'last_login_at');

        $lastLogin = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'last_login_at');


        $lastLogin->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['customer_account_edit','adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create'] 
        );
        $lastLogin->save(); 
    }
    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

Comment: `last_login_at` field is showing in database ?

Comment: yes, it is showing in database

Comment: Glad to know you found solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below function in your observer as :

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class Observerclass implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
    */
    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
) {
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
        $customerData->setCustomAttribute('last_login_at', $value);
        $customer->updateData($customerData);
        $customer->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have a question, what does this  '$value' mean?

Comment: @tremjenny, Its a variable you need to set this value as according to your requirement.

Comment: many thanks, i got it.